# Jest - Mock const variables for specific test

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to mock some constant values with specific value for a specific test. For example I've try to do this:

env.ts

```
export const VAR1: number = 1;
export const VAR2: number = 2;
```

function.ts

```
import { VAR1, VAR2 } from "./env";

export function sum(): number {
   return VAR1 + VAR2;
}
```

function.spec.ts

```
import { sum } from "../src/function";

jest.mock("../src/env", () => ({
   VAR1: 10,
   VAR2: 20,
}));

describe("module", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  test("THIS TEST WORKS FINE", () => {
    expect(sum()).toBe(30);
  });

  test("THIS TEST DOESN'T NOT WORK, sum() IS RETURNING 30", () => {
     jest.mock("../src/env", () => ({
        VAR1: 100,
        VAR2: 200,
     }));
     expect(sum()).toBe(300);
  });
});
```

The first test works fine, but the second test still using values 10 and 20. It's not using local mock.

Any suggestions to mock const values for a specific test?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, first, const shouldn't be able to be changed, so there seems to be little point in mocking a change to them. But more importantly, this is showing you a key benefit of TDD--that it exposes problems in your design that need to be fixed. If a method needs to be able to take different values and calculate from them, those values should be provided through dependency injection. In this case, that should probably be constructor injection.

```
// utils.ts
export const sum = (a: number, b: number) => a + b
```

...

```
describe('utils', () => {
    it('should add two numbers', () => {
       expect(sum(100, 200)).toBe(300)
    })
}
```

Lean on the fact .env has its own tests, and structure your code to make your tests easier to write--which will make it more generally useful and flexible--because you can then also use it for values that either aren't coming from environment variables or are coming from different ones.

Comment: The code that I left in my question is just an EXAMPLE what I want to resolve. In my real problem I have my variables like this: export const VAR1: number = process.env.ENV_VAR_1; Using its value from an environment variable. That is why I need to mock const values with another different value in my second test.

Comment: Right--you should write your code so you separate the code you want to test from the source of the variables. That's one reason it's called Test DRIVEN Development. If you write the test first, it helps you avoid the consequence of tightly coupled design.